# Get the HTML in a class from an External URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, web-scraping

I'm writing a program which prints out prices of books from flipkart.com
The roadblock I've hit right now is that I'm not able to access the DOM of the search page.
An example of a search page is here 
http://m.flipkart.com/m/search-books?query=Predictably+irrational

The prices are in spans with `class = "sp"`

Please help me access the strings in these classes (like Rs.197) using Javascript/jQuery.

I have also read a lot about the Same Origin Policy. I'd really appreciate it if you could explain a work through in detail. Thanks!

Comment: Use php to get that page html, then parse it with php aswell and return what you found via ajax back to the client in `JSON` format

Comment: You want to do it through Javascript? I guess using server side coding would be easier and efficient in doing so.

Comment: If you're planning to scrape and re-publish someone else's content without their permission, you should probably reconsider.  It's not nice.  And may even be illegal.  If you work for flipkart, or otherwise have their permission, then you should say so.

Comment: Is the page you are trying to parse inside of an iframe or is it your actual page that you have generated?

Comment: So do you guys recommend that I use php for this operation? And I definitely don't think it's illegal to scrape their data for the purpose of advertising their products. I have read their terms of use and I'm pretty sure I'm in the white area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use javascript to send an ajax request to an API you manage that does the scraping. The quickest way to do this may be with Flask/BeautifulSoup if you know Python, but if you prefer to stay in javascript you can use Node.

I don't believe you can load foreign sites in Javascript without use of an iframe, which you cannot access with javascript. (this is incorrect: see edit)

As noted in the comments, be sure that what you're doing would be okay by the site owners (can't hurt to ask them).

EDIT:

I stand corrected. You can access the data from a (no-auth only) website using http://corsproxy.com. Example: http://pastebin.com/5gfmtcPs